# Creating singleton class for mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, singleton

I am trying to write singleton  for java mongo driver. I have tried this piece of code but it is not correct. Help me to correct my logic.

```
public class MySingleton extends Mongo{
    private static MySingleton instance = null;
    private static Mongo mongo = null;

    protected MySingleton () 
          throws UnknownHostException,UnsupportedOperationException{


    }

    protected MySingleton (String ip, int port) 
               throws UnknownHostException,UnsupportedOperationException{

        mongo = new Mongo(ip,port);
        instance = (MySingleton) mongo;
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(String ip, int port) 
                     throws UnknownHostException{

        if (instance == null){
          instance =  new MySingleton(ip,port);
        }

         return instance;
    }
}
```

I am getting ClassCast exception for instance = (MySingleton) mongo;, which is obviously incorrect.

I am already aware of MongoClient. Holder.singleton(). connect() method but it does not solve my issue. So I am looking to create my own singleton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you hold another mongo instance while you are already extending it.

```
public class MySingleton extends Mongo{
    private static MySingleton instance = null;

    protected MySingleton () 
          throws UnknownHostException,UnsupportedOperationException{


    }

    protected MySingleton (String ip, int port) 
               throws UnknownHostException,UnsupportedOperationException{
        super(ip, port);
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(String ip, int port) 
                     throws UnknownHostException{

        if (instance == null){
          instance =  new MySingleton(ip,port);
        }

         return instance;
    }
}
```

If you need a mongo instance, you can use following way.

```
 Mongo m = MySingleton.getInstance(ip,port);
```

I also suggest to read following [singleton article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) so that if you may use its **Example 7. A simple singleton**.

```
public class Singleton {
   public final static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
   private Singleton() {
         // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we define implementation for MySingleton interface by MongoDB

```js
public class  implements MySingleton
{

   
}
```